# How to copy and paste an HTML div table into, eg, Excel

Tags: html, copy-paste

How do you copy an HTML div table and paste it as a table?

eg, I want to copy [this](https://www.tp-link.com/uk/compare/?typeId=5700&productIds=35621%2C35616%2C38653) comparison table into Excel, but instead of three columns I only get one. Those anti HTML table fascists have a lot to answer for.

[image: div table html]

[image: Excel single column result]

Comment: Perhaps [this Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/table-capture/iebpjdmgckacbodjpijphcplhebcmeop) might help?

Answer (score 0):

A short answer of what helped me for simple tables:

- First paste into Notepad
- Then copy and paste into Excel